# How to fire a new event using js

Tags: iccube, iccube-reporting

I'm trying to fire a 'new' event programmatically.

How can I trigger a new event (not just interfering with an existing one via customEvents function).

Can you (pls) share an example

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the reporting context, you could use event manager to fire events:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     context.eventMgr().fireExternalEvent("customEventName", customEventObj)
</script>
```

On the other hand you can fire event outside of the app, if you have access to ic3Reporting instance

for example:

```
var ic3Application = ic3.startReport(options);
```

you can fire app events in such way :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //get ic3application instance

    var ic3Application = ic3.startReport(options);
    var customEventObj = {someKey: 'someVal'};

    ic3Application.fireEvent("customEventName", customEventObj)
</script>
```

**EDIT**

If you are going to use your event in "onSelect" it might look like:

```
customEventObj = {
       selection : {
          name: 'selectionName',
          uniqueName: 'selectionUniqueName'
       }
    }
```

But still, you're free to provide any object that corresponds your needs.